# WP8 stuck on eternal loading screen

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, monogame

I am developing a C# game for Windows Phone 8 using Lumia 920 as a test device. I am using VS2012 and MonoGame 3.1.3 alpha. After I deploy my app to the device for the first time everything goes well. But on subsequent relaunches, I get a black screen with 'loading' written in the center and 5 dots above it that keep moving sideways (default windows loading indicator). *Its just like the example image below, but with 'loading' instead of 'resuming'*.
[image]

But off course it doesn't seem like its loading anything and just stays there forever. The only way to launch my app again is to uninstall it and deploy again.
The output windows ends with these 2 lines while stuck at loading:

```
The thread 0xbc4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xd40 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

This problem used to happen much less frequently last week but today it started happening every time after the first launch. I did launch in debug mode to check if there are any errors being raised but no.

Comment: Can you show your code that is run at the returning from the tombstoning entry points?

Comment: Their must be some exception handling error, in that case it happens what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about what I changed during startup lately and it is adding Parse's initialization code to my App() in App.xaml.

```
ParseObject.RegisterSubclass<ParseUserData>();
ParseClient.Initialize("---", "---");
ParseFacebookUtils.Initialize("---");
```

I moved these from the start of App() into the end of it and the problem went away.